# How do I make my bot send messages to people telling them their balance?

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase() == prefix + 'balance') {
    con.query("SELECT `Money` FROM `bloxtraderusers` WHERE id = 1", function (err,result,fields) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log(result)
       message.channel.sendMessage(result); 
    });
}
```

How can I fix this? All it does is return `[object Object]` when I do the command `$balance`?

Comment: Where does it return [object Object]? What command is $balance? Please provide more information

Comment: Oh sorry. So, it returns object object in discord. $balance command is that command, as you can see, it says if (message.content.toLowerCase() == prefix + 'balance'), which my prefix is $. So, if you type $balance in discord it returns this, however, it only returns [object Object] and when it logs it logs the actual balance. Thank you for returning a message. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Does the console show **ONLY** the balance for example `123` or does it show `Money: 123`?

I think the result you get is in fact an object with a key `Money` and the balance as value. Give this a shot:

```
message.channel.sendMessage(result.Money);
```

Comment: Gave me an error : 

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Also thank you very much for trying to help me, I appreciate it.

Comment: That error means that the object `result` doesn't have a key `Money` so your bot will try to send an empty message which Discord doesn't allow. Could you show me what the console prints when you do `console.log(result)`?

Answer (score 0):

`message.channel.sendMessage(require("util").inspect(result))`

Should do it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mysql` npm module for the database connection. `con.query` functions returns an array of objects as results. For debugging purpose, try sending the entire object as string.

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase() == prefix + 'balance') {
    con.query("SELECT `Money` FROM `bloxtraderusers` WHERE id = 1", function (err,result,fields) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log(result)
       message.channel.sendMessage(JSON.stringify(result)); 
    });
}
```